# Off-screen rendering using PixelBuffer or FBO to save all graphics to bitmap(and then to bmp/jpg) of desired size (>4096) using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I need to have ability to save all my graphics (which I render using basically code from GLSurfaceView class) to the picture file (JPG/BMP).

I chose approach which contains steps:

- Switch rendering from Window Surface to Pixel Buffer surface with required width/height - in my case this w/h should be equals to photo (my application is like photo editor)
- Read pixels using glReadPixels from current surface
- Save these pixels to Bitmap and then to JPG/BMP

But I've got a problem with this approach since there is a restriction for creating of PixelBuffer which is that size of this buffer can't be greater than EGL constants: EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT and EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH.

I found out that there are a lot of devices in which these constants equal 4096 and at the same time photo camera in these devices allows to take photos which width or height is greater than 4096. Unfortunately this makes my approach not usable.

Could you advice - how can all OpenGL graphics (which is done over some photo in my case) be saved to JPG/BMP with desired width/height (in my case it is original photo's width/height) which can be greater than EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT/EGL_MAX_PBUFFER_WIDTH?

**EDIT:**

- During investigation I found out that PBuffer approach is definitely bad since it's not working on all devices, it has problems with nvidia tegra and also it's slow
- It seems that even FBO approach (i'm not sure though, i'm investigating it now) has similar restriction - as I understand in case of FBO approach I'll need to create renderbuffer, but it's size is also can't be greater than GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE, which is 4096 on tested android devices.
- Well it seems I need to use several buffers and maybe I can try to use MappedByteBuffer to merge them and compress to jpg avoiding OOM